# How to Mock service consisting both Autowired and RequiredArgsConstructor in JUnit 5?

Tags: java, spring, mockito, junit5, springmockito

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GService {

    @Autowired
    private GRepository repository;

    private final List<GRule> rules;
```

And my test class is like this;

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class GServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private GService service;

    @Mock
    private GRepository repository;

    @Mock
    private List<GameRule> rules;
```

Rules is okay but repository is not initialized and it is null. How can I initialize the repository?

Comment: Remove `@Autowired`, make field `final`. Restart.

Comment: Is there a way to do it like that or do I have to make them all final? Is it the only way?

Comment: Unless you want to manually set them, besides that one should favor constructor injection over field injection.

Comment: you can also use `@AllArgsConstructor` if you want it not to be final (though if it's a bean- why not final?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set by using ReflectionTestUtils.setField(...) in Before Method;

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service, "repository", Mockito.mock(GRepository.class));
```